# Practice exam probability questions

Tags: probability, combinations

Going through a practice exam and have managed to answer all questions except these three, any help is greatly appreciated.

Six people have been given a sheet with a 1 on it and six people have been given a sheet with a 0 on it. If four people are needed for a demonstration of 4 bit numbers:

How many different groups of four people can be formed?

How many different combinations contain two 1's and two 0's?

How many different combinations contain at least two 1's?

Comment: 1800 users have been given 50 close votes per day and 600 of them have been given at least 5 delete votes per day. If five close votes are needed for closing a PSQ (problem statement question): How many different groups of five users with close votes can be formed?

Comment: Ignore the flavortext of $1$'s and $0$'s for now if that is what is confusing you.  Reword the question in terms of boys and girls.  You have six boys and six girls (*i.e. there are twelve students in total*).  You want to pick four of them to come to the front of the class.  Do you know how to answer *that* question? (*Answer if order of students matters.  Answer again if order of students doesn't matter*).  This should be one of the very first examples you should have learned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the formula for combinations for all of these because the ordering of the group members doesn’t matter,

$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

This formula gives you the number of unique groups that can be formed containing $r$ individuals from $n$ individuals.

For part one, you can just apply the formula with $n=12$ and $r = 4$.

For part two you’re more restricted, you’re only going to select two from the ‘1’ group and two from the ‘0’, so you’re going to have two combinations and then multiply those together:

$$\binom{6}{2}\binom{6}{2}$$

For part three, there are a couple ways to do this. You can either start at two and add that to the case when there is three and four. Or you can take all possible groupings and subtract the ones you don’t want. So below I have ‘Total - ((only one 1) + (only 0s))’

$$\binom{12}{4} - (\binom{6}{1}\binom{6}{3} + \binom{6}{0}\binom{6}{4})$$

Comment: cheers mate, this helps alot! what do the exclamation marks for the first formula signify?

Comment: also 6/0? how am i supposed to calculate that? wont that just be infinity?

Comment: @John $n!$, read aloud as $n$ *factorial*, is the number of ways of arranging $n$ distinct objects in a line.  $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n=n\cdot (n-1)!$, noting the fringe case of $0!=1$.  For example $5!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5=120$.  As for the other, the *binomial coefficient* $\binom{n}{r}$, read aloud as $n$ *choose* $r$, is the number of ways of selecting an $r$-element subset of an $n$-element set, and is algebraically equal to $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$.  For example $\binom{6}{3}=\frac{6!}{3!3!}=20$.  It is not division by zero, so no it would not "just be infinity"

Comment: These should have been explained in virtually every elementary text on counting principles as introductory examples, and they are such necessary and useful examples that their results are given these special symbols and notations so we can quickly write down their answers as they appear in larger problems.  Proving the given formulas actually count what I said they do is an important exercise to go through in first learning how to count.

Comment: @John my bad I should have been more explicit in my answer. I wasn’t sure what level you are at. But whenever you have $r=0$ the combination formula evaluates to 1 because $0! = 1$. Also if you could give me an upvote on the answer that would be helpful. Cheers